# Show Javadoc in IntelliJ/Android Studio without publishing sources

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, nexus

we are creating an Android library and want enable our users to see the Javadoc in `AndroidStudio/Intellij`.

To test this I published the javadoc and sources to nexus and everything worked fine.
But actually I don't want to provide our sources to every user, as it is no OS project.

But without the sources I was not able to to get any javadoc shown.

Can anyone help me?

Additional Information:

When I deploy only the Javadoc AndroidStudio does not recognize them. The xml under ".idea/libraries/" looks the following:

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="adapter-0.4.324">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.android/build-cache/77393c6313510bd47cb4d4c9344c0d5fea59b1a0/output/jars/classes.jar!/" />
      <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.android/build-cache/77393c6313510bd47cb4d4c9344c0d5fea59b1a0/output/res" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES />
  </library>
</component>
```

as soon as I deploy the sources AndroidStudio recognizes them and is adding them to the xml. I'm also able to see Javadoc in Android Studio:

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="adapter-0.4.324">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.android/build-cache/77393c6313510bd47cb4d4c9344c0d5fea59b1a0/output/jars/classes.jar!/" />
      <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.android/build-cache/77393c6313510bd47cb4d4c9344c0d5fea59b1a0/output/res" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.m2/repository/[package]/0.4.324/adapter-0.4.324-sources.jar!/" />
    </SOURCES>
  </library>
</component>
```

To clarify my question: I want to deploy Javadoc to nexus -> AndroidStudio should show the javadoc automatically.

Regardless I'm able to add the javadoc manually via library properties. But I don't want to add them after every release again. The xml is updated correctly after that:

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="adapter-0.4.324">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.android/build-cache/77393c6313510bd47cb4d4c9344c0d5fea59b1a0/output/jars/classes.jar!/" />
      <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.android/build-cache/77393c6313510bd47cb4d4c9344c0d5fea59b1a0/output/res" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.m2/repository/[package]/0.4.324/adapter-0.4.324-javadoc.jar!/" />
    </JAVADOC>
    <SOURCES />
  </library>
</component>
```

Comment: You can generate and publish JavaDoc to the repository without the sources.

Comment: @CrazyCoder added some additional Information to my question. The question was probably not clear enough. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug. Found the following bug reports:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37125917
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64061645